# Removing space between printed generated passwords

Tags: python, passwords

I wrote a Python script to crack the password of forgotten accounts.
However, everytime I print a password, there is a space between "Hacked/hacked" and whatever else.

I suspect that the space character is somewhere in the password variables. No matter what I do, my IDE won't let me remove that space between the quotes in the password variable. How can I remove it?

Here's the code:

```py
while True:
   import random
   num ="12"
   ans = num + "-"
   ans2 = num + "/"
   ans3 = num + "_"
   length = 3
   password ="".join(random.sample(ans,length))
   password2 ="".join(random.sample(ans2,length))
   password3 ="".join(random.sample(ans3,length))
   print("Hacked",password)
   print("hacked",password)
   print("Hacked",password2)
   print("hacked",password2)
   print("Hacked",password3)
```

Comment: Did you mean: `print("Hacked" + password)` etc ?

Comment: Oof. Forgot to try that. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several ways to solve this:

```
print(f'HACKED{var}')
print('HACKED'+var)
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, `print()` separates each argument passed to it with a space. You can override this by specifying the `sep` parameter (in this case, you want to use the empty string as the separator). For example, you can do the following:

```py
print("Hacked", password, sep="")
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition, you could also use an f-string to format your output:

```py
print(f"Hacked{password}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Got a straightforward solution

```
print("Hacked"+password)
```

Instead of

```
print("Hacked",password)
#but if you just want to stick to this method,
print("Hacked",password sep= "") #this may be the solution for you.
```